# How to evaluate $\int _0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln \left(x\right)\ln \left(1-x\right)\ln \left(1+x\right)}{1+x}\:dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to evaluate: $$\int _0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln \left(x\right)\ln \left(1-x\right)\ln \left(1+x\right)}{1+x}\:dx,$$ but I don't see how can I achieve so.

My attempts so far have been rewriting the integral using algebraic identities such as: $$ab=\frac{1}{2}a^2+\frac{1}{2}b^2-\frac{1}{2}\left(a-b\right)^2=\frac{1}{4}\left(a+b\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}\left(a-b\right)^2,$$ that yield other integrals like:
$$\int _0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln \left(x\right)\ln ^2\left(1-x\right)}{1+x}\:dx,\:\int _0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln \left(x\right)\ln ^2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{1+x}\:dx.$$Normally the beta function and expanding terms into series is used to deal with these kind of integrals yet neither can be used because of the upper bound.

What else can be done in order to compute the main integral? Thanks.

Comment: If the upper limit was $1$ it would *maybe* be possible to get a closed form. With the $1/2$ you're out of luck.

Comment: @K.defaoite For when the upper bound is $1$ the integral is way easier and the closed form is very well known ,$$\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(x\right)\ln \left(1-x\right)\ln \left(1+x\right)}{1+x}\:dx=-2\zeta \left(4\right)+2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{21}{8}\ln \left(2\right)\zeta \left(3\right)-\frac{5}{4}\ln ^2\left(2\right)\zeta \left(2\right)+\frac{1}{12}\ln ^4\left(2\right)$$

Answer (score 4):

I think that I should expand one part of the integrand as a Taylor series around $x=0$.

For symmetry reasons, I chose
$$\frac{\log (1-x) \log (x+1)}{x+1}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n\,(x^{2n+1}-x^{2n})$$  where the $a_n$'s make the sequence
$$\left\{1,\frac{17}{12},\frac{151}{90},\frac{9413}{5040},\frac{5647}{2800},\frac{444
   811}{207900},\frac{84902267}{37837800},\frac{706664611}{302702400},\cdots\right\}$$ and use
$$I_n=\int_0^{\frac 12}(x^{2n+1}-x^{2n})\,\log(x)\,dx=$$
$$\frac{(7+6 \log (2))+ 2(6+11 \log (2))\,n+4 (1+6 \log (2))\,n^2+8  \log
   (2)\,n^3}{4^{n+2}\,(n+1)^2 \,(2 n+1)^2}$$ and the partial sums
$$S_p=\sum_{k=1}^p a_k\,I_k$$ converge quite fast
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & S_p \\
 1 & 0.02803334672 \\
 2 & 0.03276936442 \\
 3 & 0.03366455049 \\
 4 & 0.03384586175 \\
 5 & 0.03388419298 \\
 6 & 0.03389253226 \\
 7 & 0.03389438389 \\
 8 & 0.03389480131 \\
 9 & 0.03389489653 \\
 10 & 0.03389491845 \\
 11 & 0.03389492353 \\
 12 & 0.03389492472 \\
 13 & 0.03389492500 \\
 14 & 0.03389492506 \\
 15 & 0.03389492508
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

You could use this for any other value of the upper bound since
$$J_n=\int_0^{t}(x^{2n+1}-x^{2n})\,\log(x)\,dx=$$
$$ t^{2n+1}\Bigg[\frac{1}{(2 n+1)^2}-\frac{t}{4(n+1)^2} +\frac{(2n+1)t-2(n+1) }{2(n+1) (2 n+1) }\log(t)\Bigg]$$

Answer (score 2):

An idea by **Cornel Ioan Valean**

Exploit the result
$$f(a)=\int_0^{1/2} \frac{\log (x) \log (1-x)}{1-a x} \textrm{d}x$$
$$\small =\frac{1}{2 a}\log ^3(2)-\frac{3 }{4 a}\zeta (3)-\frac{\log ^2(2) }{2 a}\log \left(1-\frac{a}{2}\right)-\frac{\log ^2(2) }{2 a}\log \left(\frac{a-2}{a-1}\right)+\frac{\log(2)}{a}\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)$$
$$\small+\frac{\log (2) }{a}\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a}{2 (a-1)}\right)+\frac{1}{a}\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{a}\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{a}{2 (a-1)}\right)-\frac{1}{a}\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{a}{a-1}\right)-\frac{\text{Li}_3(a-1)}{a}.$$

This is a modified form of **Lemma 2** in the paper  **A special way of extracting the real part of the Trilogarithm,  $\displaystyle  \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1\pm i}{2}\right)$** easily obtained by the means presented in the paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337868999_A_special_way_of_extracting_the_real_part_of_the_Trilogarithm_Li_31i2

**A nice fact:** maybe good to mention also this integral variant

$$\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\log(1-x)\log(x)\log(1+x)}{x}\textrm{d}x=\int_{-1}^0 f(a) da.$$

Comment: Nice solution !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you! Just a good idea to consider. :-)